# How to handle facebook login with a subdomain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-cloudfront, facebook-authentication

My application client side serve using aws cloudfront/s3. `www.example.com`

My server side is nodejs in ec2. `api.example.com`

I want to do login with facebook.

I set facebook to redirect after login to `api.example.com/api/facebook/return`.

Now when I on `api.example.com/api/facebook/return` I need to get back to my application `www.example.com` with the user loggedin.

How to do it?

- I don't want to use lambda (lets say this is not the solution for me).
- I can't access to the localStorage to store the token and the user - cause safari doesn't support `Hub` in access to another localStronge domain.
- Can't use cookie because I have LoadBalancer and stateless servers.
- I try to send a 10 seconds token to the client and return back to the server (confirm the token) and then back to the client (access token).
  but sometimes the computer is slow and I get expired.

I was thinking about one time token, but how to implement such a thing? or **any other idea** how to handle this?

Comment: This is the exact flow I have used in my app very recently and you can do two things,
1. `api.example.com/api/facebook/return` along with return you will be getting auth_code in params from facebook which should be used to fetch access token and after fetching access token redirect to your application home screen with access/refreshToken in params.

2. Redirect from return URL to your application with auth_code and let client app fetch the accessTokens/RefreshTokens.

Comment: but I need to get to my home screen with a user loggedin. I mean when I redirect to my home screen I see that I loggedin.- this is missing how I do it?

Comment: Yes, only if you have logged in from Facebook you ll get accessToken, and you can assume the user is already logged in if you have accessToken in your params and using accessToken you can fetch further details about user.

Comment: but this auth_code need to check once. after that it need to be invalid. any idea how to do that?

Comment: By default, auth_code after once you use will become invalid and noone can use again the same auth_code to generate the accessToken. Moreover if you go with first approach, you will be getting the access token directly in client_app and need not worry about auth_code invalidity.